# css repeat part of way

Tags: css, repeat

is there a way to only repeat a background part of the way down a div.  I want to have one background repeat-y for say 90% of the div, and then have a different background for the bottom.  right now I have both backgrounds, but since the bottom one has a gradient to clear it's getting "covered up" by the repeat-y background above it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the easiest way is to create an additional `<div>` inside of your current one. Set that `<div>`'s height to 90% and assign the background to *that* inside `<div>` instead.

e.g.

HTML

```
<div id="outer-div">
    <div id="inner-div">...content...</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* example outer div */
#outer-div
{
    height:500px; /* This is an example rule */
    width: 200px; /* This is an example rule */
}

#inner-div
{
    height:90%;
    background:#000;
}
```

Comment: hmmmmm, I do like this, just not sure I can implement it, I'm working from a hub which adds content on it's own.  let me try it

Comment: ok, got it.  thanks a bunch, I have to wait 5 minutes before I can accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create multiple backgrounds with CSS3 using only one div:

```
background: 
   url(bottom.png) no-repeat,     /* On top,    like z-index: 2; */
   url(top.png) repeat-y,         /*            like z-index: 1; */
```

Repeat your top image, the bottom image will then be displayed over this.

Comment: Quick note: CSS3 multiple backgrounds not supported by IE8 or earlier.